# Removing all variables in a list except strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to remove all variables within a list but keep only strings, how can I do this?

I just need to get all other variables except strings out of the list, but I cannot find any working solutions.

```py
list1 = ["9.0","python","java","c++",123,"c#", True, False]

for a in list1:
     list1.remove(int(a))

print(list1)
```

In addition, only programming languages should stay.

Comment: For your last requirement, you're going to need an additional reference source of known programming languages. Assume you have that?

Comment: Do you want `"9.0"` left in the list or not?

Comment: create a `set` of programming languages, do a set intersection with your `list1`-- or if the order matters then do `[x for x in list1 if x in set_of_languages]`

Comment: [96](https://esolangs.org/wiki/96) is also a language, should this be removed?

Comment: [123](https://esolangs.org/wiki/123) is also a programming language, theres no way to do this without a resource list as commented above

Answer (score 2):

You can just a try/except loop to test if the string can convert to a float, then filter out the strings/objects that can be converted.  This will remove ints, floats, bools, and strings that can convert to floats such as `'9.0'`.

```py
def float_test(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

list(filter(lambda x: not float_test(x), list1))
# returns:
['python', 'java', 'c++', 'c#']
```

Answer (score 2):

The linear way to do this builds the `list` from scratch with a comprehension. This is more efficient than repeated `remove` calls. You can use slice assignment to mutate the original `list` object. The string condition seems obsolete as all languages are strings to start with:

```
list1 = ["9.0", "python", "java", "c++", 123, "c#", True, False]

langs = {"python", "java", "c++", "c#"}  # need some source of languages

list1[:] = [x for x in list1 if x in langs]
# ['python', 'java', 'c++', 'c#']
```

Comment: "In addition, only programming languages should stay."

Comment: @Sayse Well spotted :D RTFQ

Answer (score 0):

```
def stringExtractor(list_of_stuff):
    new_li = []
    for i in list_of_stuff:
        try:
            new_li.append(float(i))
        except ValueError:
            new_li.append(i)
            pass
    return new_li


new_list = stringExtractor(list1)
new_list = [i for i in new_list if isinstance(i, str)]
print(new_list)

# Output: ['python', 'java', 'c++', 'c#']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the bunch with this `numpy`/`pandas` overkill:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

list1 = ["9.0","python","java","c++",123,"c#", True, False]

np.array(list1)[np.isnan(pd.to_numeric(list1, errors='coerce'))]

#array(['python', 'java', 'c++', 'c#'], dtype='<U6')
```